# General performance comparison between ImmutableList and List?

Tags: c#, list, immutability

I think ImmutableList is much slower than List in adding and removing an element. Is that right?

Benchmarked. Perforamce of ImmutableList to add and RemoveAt is good. RemoveAt is even faster than List.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Generic List Test
        var genericList = new List<int>();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            genericList.Add(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Add duration for List<T>: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        IList<int> completeList = new List<int>(genericList);

        sw.Restart();

        // Remove from 20000 -> 0.
        for (int i = completeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            genericList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Remove duration for List<T>: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Items after remove for List<T>: " + genericList.Count);


        // ImmutableList Test
        var immutableList = ImmutableList<int>.Empty;

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            immutableList = immutableList.Add(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Add duration for ImmutableList<T>: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();

        // Remove from 20000 -> 0.
        for (int i = completeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            immutableList = immutableList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Remove duration for ImmutableList<T>: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Items after remove for ImmutableList<T>: " + immutableList.Count);
    }
```

Results

```
Add duration for List<T>: 0
Remove duration for List<T>: 37
Items after remove for List<T>: 0
Add duration for ImmutableList<T>: 22
Remove duration for ImmutableList<T>: 14
Items after remove for ImmutableList<T>: 0
```

Comment: Benchmark and compare for your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's honestly a myth that immutability means lacking performance.

I would expect that many operations would be faster with an immutable list.

The implementation of immutable list uses a binary search tree, which has favorable performance characteristics compared to arrays for searches, inserts, and deletes. There still is the overhead from copying that factors into play. So, there will be a tipping point in which one will perform better than the other.

Results from my machine for deletes (Immutable/Regular) milliseconds

```
     Deletes  100       1000      10000     100000
Count         
 1000         4/0       na        na        na
10000         4/0       5/1       na        na  
  1e5         4/2       5/23      22/215    na  
  1e6         7/44      8/431     37/4676   118/44081 
  1e7         8/718     7/7363    36/77638  110/x*
  1e8         8/7594    9/76200   31/781349 113/x* 

* I didn't have the patience to finish benchmarking here.
```

Comment: which method do you use to delete? Remove or RemoveAt?

Comment: `RemoveAt()`. I wasn't interested in conflating the results with the benchmark of search + delete.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Since ImmutableList is implemented using height balanced tree, for RemoveAt, the rebalance process for ImmutableList should be much quicker than shifting the elements in a List (backed by an array) unless the item is at the end of the List

I see this asked in many places many times, always benchmarking is the right thing to do answer such questions empirically, but please make sure to measure memory as well and use benchmark.net

However, always remember that in real world applications concurrency and GC plays a big part in determining the performance.

Knowing the GC impact due to the collection is critical as the memory increase might sometimes halt the GC and thereby slowing down the app it influences

With regards to concurrency, Adding into a list is O(1) operation theoretically assuming we ignore multiple threads reading/writing and we also ignore that the size of the underlying array has not reached its capacity.

The most ideal scenario for performance would be using a host that is single threaded and where we can use a mutable collection and having multiple instances of such hosts for any entity it wraps, eg: Actors. It is also subject to how Actors are implemented.

If we cannot use actors, then we are left with manual synchronization of access which is error prone and we might end up with poor performance even after done right due to the nature of concurrency, eg: multiple readers and writers resulting in lots of copys

Since there is a lot of parameters involved in deciding which collection is the right choice for a particular scenario, the sane default can be assumed as using Immutable collections

- correctness is guaranteed
- speed is often at par with the mutable collections, if not only slightly worse
- all the collections except ImmutableArray use a height balanced binary search tree, the nodes are re-used on modifications causing only a small overhead on GC

Think about mutable only when the performance is highly critical and there is no way to achieve higher performance without changing the data structure

Answer (score -5):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

> When you add or remove items from an immutable list, a copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.

Because of the copy, it will be slower.